# Retrieve the contents of a POST method

Tags: web-scraping

I'm trying to get the data behind a flash website. To do this, I used firebug and found a POST method under the Net tab that contains the data I want. I can see this data just by clicking on the POST method in Firebug, but when I do so the url displayed is not different than the whole webpage. Is there a persistent url for this data? If so, what is it? If not, how can I get to this data without using firebug? I'm going to want to scrape it using Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

`POST` send data to server and server send back page which url you have.

You can see what data was send from browser to server but you can get it back from server.

This data are derived from data in form on (previous) page or they are created by javascript on page. First type you put in form on page on your own, second type requires analizing of javascript code.

**BTW:** in Firebug you have two types of data - data send from browser to server (so called `POST` data, send as `Request`) and data send from server to browser (send as `Response`) which you can see as page in browser.

Comment: Okay, I understand this now. So all I have to do is POST the same data to the server, and the response is what I want. Thanks for the help.